# Compiling LuaSQL 2.1.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 for odbc

Tags: ubuntu, odbc, ubuntu-10.04, luasql

I can't get luasql 2.1.1 for odbc to compile out of the box, and I don't understand how to interpret the error. This is on Ubuntu 10.04, and unixodbc is successfully installed.

```
root@server:~/Downloads/luasql-2.1.1# make
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -ansi -pedantic -I../compat/src -DUNIXODBC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include    -c -o src/luasql.o src/luasql.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -ansi -pedantic -I../compat/src -DUNIXODBC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include    -c -o src/ls_odbc.o src/ls_odbc.c
src/ls_odbc.c: In function ‘fail’:
src/ls_odbc.c:134: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 6 of ‘SQLGetDiagRec’ differ in signedness
/usr/include/sql.h:708: note: expected ‘SQLCHAR *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
src/ls_odbc.c: In function ‘push_column’:
src/ls_odbc.c:197: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘SQLGetData’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/sql.h:685: note: expected ‘SQLLEN *’ but argument is of type ‘SQLINTEGER *’
src/ls_odbc.c:210: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘SQLGetData’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/sql.h:685: note: expected ‘SQLLEN *’ but argument is of type ‘SQLINTEGER *’
src/ls_odbc.c:230: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘SQLGetData’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/sql.h:685: note: expected ‘SQLLEN *’ but argument is of type ‘SQLINTEGER *’
src/ls_odbc.c:245: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘SQLGetData’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/sql.h:685: note: expected ‘SQLLEN *’ but argument is of type ‘SQLINTEGER *’
src/ls_odbc.c: In function ‘create_colinfo’:
src/ls_odbc.c:383: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of ‘lua_pushstring’ differ in signedness
/usr/local/include/lua.h:164: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘SQLCHAR *’
src/ls_odbc.c: In function ‘conn_execute’:
src/ls_odbc.c:468: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of ‘SQLPrepare’ differ in signedness
/usr/include/sql.h:743: note: expected ‘SQLCHAR *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
src/ls_odbc.c:497: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘SQLRowCount’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/sql.h:749: note: expected ‘SQLLEN *’ but argument is of type ‘SQLINTEGER *’
src/ls_odbc.c: In function ‘env_connect’:
src/ls_odbc.c:602: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of ‘SQLConnect’ differ in signedness
/usr/include/sql.h:614: note: expected ‘SQLCHAR *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
src/ls_odbc.c:602: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 4 of ‘SQLConnect’ differ in signedness
/usr/include/sql.h:614: note: expected ‘SQLCHAR *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
src/ls_odbc.c:602: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 6 of ‘SQLConnect’ differ in signedness
/usr/include/sql.h:614: note: expected ‘SQLCHAR *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.3"; gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -ansi -pedantic -I../compat/src -DUNIXODBC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include  -o src/odbc.so -shared  src/luasql.o src/ls_odbc.o  -L/usr/local/lib -lodbc
/usr/bin/ld: src/luasql.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
src/luasql.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [src/odbc.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the -fPIC flag as suggested in the WARN variable in luasql-2.x/config. Thanks!